# XPath: Search for several nodes in specific order

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a XML file with "hello" nodes containing "word" nodes:

```
<doc>
    <hello>
        <word>Hello</word><word>World</word><word>!</word>
    </hello>
    <hello>
        <word>Hello</word><word>!</word><word>World</word>
    </hello>
    <hello>
        <word>Hello</word><word>World</word><word>!</word><word>blorf</word>
    </hello>
    <hello>
        <word>Hello</word><word>Wo</word><word>rld!</word>
    </hello>
</doc>
```

I want to match the only the first `hello`. The second one has the wrong order, and the third one has an extra word. The fourth has the right text, but divided into words incorrectly.

---

This query works in XPath 1.0 but is extremely wordy. Is there a simpler way?

```
//hello[count(word) = 3 and word[1] = "Hello" and word[2] = "World" and word[3] = "!"]
```

---

This works in XPath 2.0. Is there any way to do equivalent in XPath 1.0?

```
//hello[deep-equal(data(subsequence(word,1)),('Hello','World','!'))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using XPath 2.0, you can use `string-join()` to add a delimiter to separate the individual words.

```
//hello[string-join(word,'|')='Hello|World|!']
```

You may need to use `normalize-space(word)` if white-space is supposed to be ignored.

Another XPath 2.0 alternative is to use `deep-equal()` to compare two sequences. This would be safer because it's not using a delimiter that might be part of the text value.

```
//hello[deep-equal(data(subsequence(word,1)),('Hello','World','!'))]
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is not entirely better than BeniBela's, but the second is exactly what i was looking for. Is there no way to emulate it in xpath 1.0?

Comment: @bukzor - As far as I know, there is no way to emulate this in 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below **XPATH 1.0**

```
//hello[
  word[1][
    .='Hello' and following-sibling::word[1][
      .='World' and following-sibling::word[1][
        .='!' and count(following-sibling::word)=0
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

**output**

```
<hello>
    <word>Hello</word><word>World</word><word>!</word>
</hello>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a solution that doesn't require indexing each child? The contained phrase may be variable length.

Comment: @bukzor I didn't get you... Probably you are using XPATH2.0.. I use only 1.0 version.. But what do you mean by garbage?

Comment: @bukzor You want only when `world` will be next to `hello` ..right ?

Answer (score 1):

Just treat the entire Hello-node as text:

```
//hello[normalize-space(.) = "HelloWorld!"]
```

Comment: BeniBela: Thanks! Your method works for the simple cases presented above, but drops all notion of structure. I've added a fourth case that your query matches but shouldn't.